# Excel OWC Hyperlink formatting

Tags: excel

I am creating an excel file output in c# using OWC11 components. The output excel has multiple tab and each of this tab has one column which is a filepath + filename. I would like to format this column as hyperlink so the users should be able to open the file on click.

Is there a way to format this output column as hyperlink, using OWC format somehow?

Please Advise,

thanks for you help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to figure this out with following change to column formatting 
=HYPERLINK("file:////hyperlinkvalue","text")
thanks for suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

why not just formulate your output into excel as a hyperlink?

as in `<a href="blah.whtvr">` and paste that into the cells